# EE google maps not displaying on contact page

Tags: channel

we have taken over an EE page from another guy
www.fitnesscoach.lu
in the "contact-area" the google maps is not showing anymore
any indication where i can find it in the backend and how to fix
tks

Answer (score 0):

There's many possibilities!.. Which EE version are you using? (I check the admin login and it looks like you have EE 2.x

1. The code is "hard coded" in the template.
2. They put the google map code in a Variable OR an snippet
3. They use an Addon..

But as i can see the problem is that the Map was in the "MyMap" developer account and he deleted it...

If you need more help let me know..